# [Swift]How an annotationview always show callout

Tags: swift, annotations, mkmapview

I want to show the `callout` of the `annotationview` always show, I mean when the `mapview` is loaded, all the annotations‘ `callout` is shown.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At anytime, there can be only one callout on the map. Framework reuses the previous callout when a new is to be presented, and here is showing **a single** callout view when annotation is added, like so

```
let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
annotation.title = "Title for Callout"
mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

This causes the delegate method `viewForAnnotation` to be fired:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    let view = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "AnnotId")
    view.canShowCallout = true
    return view
}
```

Framework will add the above returned view and the `didAddViews` delegate is fired, now show the callout view by selecting the annnotation, like so

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didAdd views: [MKAnnotationView]) {
    if let annotation = views.first(where: { $0.reuseIdentifier == "AnnotId" })?.annotation {
        mapView.selectAnnotation(annotation, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Add annotation on map: `mapView.addAnnotation(myAnnotation)`
2. Select annotation `mapView.selectAnnotation(myAnnotation, animated: false)`
3. Add private function `private func bringMyAnnotationToFront()` with code `if let myAnnotation = mapView.annotations.first(where: { $0 is MKPointAnnotation }) { mapview.selectAnnotation(myAnnotation, animated: false) }`
4. Set MKMapViewDelegate and implement two methods with `bringMyAnnotationToFront`:
   `func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView)`, `func mapView(MKMapView, didDeselect: MKAnnotationView)`